# Domain credentials for a WebClient class don't work

Tags: c#, .net, windows, credentials, windowsdomainaccount

I'm trying to get a HTML source of a website through C# code. When I access the site with Windows Authentication, the following code works:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://intranet/"))
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
```

When I enter my domain credentials manually, I get an "unauthenticated" message.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "domain");
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://intranet/"))
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try this:

```
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
    new Uri("http://intranet/"), 
    "NTLM", 
    new NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "domain"));
client.Credentials = cc;
```

Comment: You need to specify the authentication type. When the server challenges the client with NTLM authentication the ICredentials.GetCredential method will be called on WebClient.Credentials with `authType = "NTLM"`. If you used `WebClient.Credential = new NetworkCredential(...)` as no authentication type is specified the client won't be able to respond correctly. `CredentialCache` already implements this functionality.

Comment: What should I specify in Uri? Resource I am trying to get is "https://myDomain.com/images/userName". Can you put any live example how Uri and NetworkCredentials should look like? Thx

Comment: Good answear, and I´d like to point out that if you don´t want to create a new NetworkCredential you can get the default ones from DefaultNetworkCredentials: `NetworkCredential networkCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.GetCredential(uri, "NTLM")`

Comment: I don't believe that this technique will work if the client app is running on IIS 8.5 - at least I could not get this working there.  Works OK on an IIS 7.5 instance

Comment: This is not working for me .. I am using Windows authentication and tried to use this for it... Even the post says windows authentication …