# Loop thorough multiple HTML tables in HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I followed the example in the below link and was able to parse HTML table successfully to a datatable.

http://blog.ditran.net/parsing-html-table-to-c-usable-datalist/

But I am not able to parse multiple tables,When I traverse through TR the first TR always have the column names and the rest have the data in each table.So I am using this logic and storing the table data in dictionary and sending to my ToDataTable function.

Can someone help on how can I loop thoriugh multiple tables and implement the same logic.Appreciate it.

```
var tRowList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");
foreach (HtmlNode tRow in tRowList)
                    {
                        if (previousRowSpanList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            theDict = previousRowSpanList[0];
                            previousRowSpanList.Remove(theDict);        //remove it off the list
                            isWorkingWithRowSpan = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            theDict = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                            isWorkingWithRowSpan = false;
                        }
                        var tCellList = tRow.SelectNodes("td|th");
                        tCelCount = tCellList.Count;
                        if (tCelCount > 0 &&
                        !(tCelCount == 1 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(tCellList[0].InnerText.Trim()))
                        )
                        {
                            //colOrder = 1;
                            IsNullEntireRow = true;
                            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < tCelCount; colIndex++)
                            {
                                cell = tCellList[colIndex];
                                ColInnerText = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Trim();
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ColInnerText))
                                    IsNullEntireRow = false;
```

//

```
 static DataTable ToDataTable(List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> list)
        {
            DataTable result = new DataTable();
            if (list.Count == 0)
                return result;

            result.Columns.AddRange(
        list.First().Select(r => new DataColumn(r.Value)).ToArray()
    );



            list= list.Skip(1).ToArray().ToList();
            list.ForEach(r => result.Rows.Add(r.Select(c => c.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray()));


            return result;
```

sample HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Node</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Logtime</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Hardware</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Prcstate A</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Prcstate B</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Cluster</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">RAID</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">AD replication A</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">AD replication B</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">File replication A</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">File replication B</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;font-weight:bold;" class="center">hcstart RESULT</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">DTMSCB1</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:40</td><td class="center">APG43L</td><td class="center">active</td><td class="center">passive</td><td class="center">-</td><td class="center">-</td><td class="center">-</td><td class="center">-</td><td class="center">-</td><td class="center">-</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Not OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">MSC9</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:40</td><td class="center">APG40C/4</td><td class="center">passive</td><td class="center">active</td><td class="center">OK</td><td class="center">OK</td><td class="center">OK</td><td class="center">OK</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">Not OK</td><td class="center">OK</td><td class="center">-</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;" class="center">Node Type</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;" class="center">Node</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;" class="center">Log Time</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;" class="center">New Mon. Alarms</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;" class="center">Mon. Alarms Total</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;" class="center">Other Alarms</td><td style="background-color:#A9F5A9;" class="center">MML</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">BSC</td><td class="center">BMBSC1</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">46</td><td class="center">445</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">BSC</td><td class="center">BMBSC2C</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">27</td><td class="center">609</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">BSC</td><td class="center">CYBSC1</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">1</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">45</td><td class="center">665</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">BSC</td><td class="center">CYBSC2C</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">30</td><td class="center">849</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">MSC-BC</td><td class="center">CYMSCB1</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">38</td><td class="center">283</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">BSC</td><td class="center">DTBSC1</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">48</td><td class="center">201</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">BSC</td><td class="center">DTBSC2</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">1</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">31</td><td class="center">310</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">MSC-BC</td><td class="center">DTMSCB1</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">25</td><td class="center">130</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">HLR</td><td class="center">HLR1</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">16</td><td class="center">12</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">HLR</td><td class="center">HLR2</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">24</td><td class="center">10</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">MSC-S</td><td class="center">MSC10</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">48</td><td class="center">79</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
<tr><td class="center">MSC-S</td><td class="center">MSC9</td><td class="center">2016-08-26 16:45</td><td class="center">0</td><td style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;" class="center">46</td><td class="center">131</td><td class="center">OK</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First find the tables nodes `var tableList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");` and iterate over this list to find the corresponding table rows

Comment: how do I get only the corresponding tr and td..   . the below code is giving null..      var tCellList = tRow.SelectNodes("tr|td");

Comment: I want to loop thorugh one table tr and get the dictionary object and then loop through other one..

Comment: see provided example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll keep the first answer for reference, but below is a method that will split the original html into a string array with each string element containing the HTML for one table:

```
public static string[] ParseHtmlSplitTables(string htmlString)
{
    string[] result = new string[] { };

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(htmlString))
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

        var tableNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
        if (tableNodes != null)
        {
            result = Array.ConvertAll<HtmlNode, string>(tableNodes.ToArray(), n => n.OuterHtml);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

With the result you can then proceed to parse each table:

```
string[] htmlTables = ParseHtmlSplitTables(htmlString);

foreach (string html in htmlTables)
{
    List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> parseResult = ParseHtmlToDataTable(html);

    DataTable dataTable = ToDataTable(parseResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to parse multiple html tables you should return a `DataSet` that will have one `DataTable` per html table. If table headers are present, the code below will add column names to the corresponding `DataTable`. The html table id will be used as the name for the `DataTable` with which you can use to directly access from the `DataSet`:

Method to convert html tables to a `DataSet`:

```
public static DataSet HtmlTablesToDataset(string html)
{
    var resultDataset = new DataSet();

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
    {
        var resultTable = new DataTable(table.Id);

        foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
        {
            var headerCells = row.SelectNodes("th");
            if (headerCells != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode cell in headerCells)
                {
                    resultTable.Columns.Add(cell.InnerText);
                }
            }

            var dataCells = row.SelectNodes("td");
            if (dataCells != null)
            {
                var dataRow = resultTable.NewRow();
                for (int i=0; i < dataCells.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataRow[i] = dataCells[i].InnerText;
                }

                resultTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
        }

        resultDataset.Tables.Add(resultTable);
    }

    return resultDataset;
}
```

Test code:

```
var resultDS = HtmlTablesToDataset(html);

foreach(DataTable dt in resultDS.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Table: " + dt.TableName);

    string line = "";

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        line += col.ToString() + " ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(line.Trim());

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        line = "";
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            line += row[col].ToString() + " ";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(line.Trim());
    }
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
string html =
@"
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='t1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id='t2'>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>        
        </table>
    </body>
</html>                
";
```

Comment: I don't have headers or tables ID's  in the HTML.. provided my sample HTML. I want to parse two tables separately.. with first item in my dictionary as columns and rest everything as rows/data.we have to name tables manually..that is fine..I also handled Row/Col span in the link(http://blog.ditran.net/parsing-html-table-to-c-usable-datalist/) .. has the complete code.Please advise..

Comment: @user1046415 Ok, I see from the sample html that the two tables have  different columns so we'll need to split the table nodes into separate html strings then process them separately

Comment: @user1046415 I've add my second answer below based on your comments