# Replicate cURL Command Using Redirect and Cookies in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, curl, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

This one seems a long shot.  But I have seen several answers that indicate that HttpClient (and similar) should be used when cURL is needed in a .Net Core Application.

I have the following cURL command (that works perfectly):

```
curl -v -L --negotiate -u : -b ~/cookiejar.txt  "https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5001&client_id=client_id_here"
```

The flow of this command goes like this:

1. Loads the provided url (https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize....)
2. Gets a 302 response to redirect to https://idp.domain.net/iwa-kerberos?state=state_guid_here

   - Because the `-L` option is there, it follows the redirect
3. The redirect responds with a 401 (Unauthorized) with a `www-authenticate:Negotiate` header.
4. cURL sees the `www-authenticate:Negotiate` header and gets a Kerberos token from the operating system (because of the `--negotiate` and `-u` options).
5. cURL calls the redirect url (https://idp.domain.net/iwa-kerberos?state=state_guid_here) with an additional header of `Authorization: Negotiate <kerberos token here>`.
6. A response of 302 returned redirecting to https://idp.domain.net/commonauth?state=state_guid_here&iwaauth=1 with **an added cookie**

   - Because of the `-b` option, the cookie is picked up by cURL.
7. cURL calls the redirect url (https://idp.domain.net/commonauth?state=state_guid_here&iwaauth=1) **with the cookie returned in the 302 of the previous step**.
8. Another 302 redirect is returned.  Redirecting to https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize?sessionDataKey=session_key_guid_here **with more cookies**. (Again picked up because of the `-b` option.)
9. The redirect to https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize?sessionDataKey=session_key_guid_here is followed **with the added cookies**.
10. Another 302 redirect is returned to  https://localhost:5001/?code=code_guid_here&session_state=session_state_here (with an added cookie).
11. cURL folows the redirect to https://localhost:5001/?code=code_guid_here&session_state=session_state_here with the added cookie.
12. Contents of https://localhost:5001/?code=code_guid_here&session_state=session_state_here are returned to the cURL command line.

Writing this all out, it seems like a serious undertaking to get this to work in a .Net Application.  But I figured I would ask in case it is built in to the framework somewhere.

**Is there a .Net Core Framework class (or similar) that can allow me to reproduce this cURL command in C# code?**

NOTE: I am able to do it by calling out to powershell.  This question is about doing it with `HttpClient`.

Comment: And if you try to just use `HttpClient` (with `UseDefaultCredentials = true`) then on which step it fails?

Comment: @Evk - With `UseDefaultCredentials` and `AllowAutoRedirect` both set to true it gets to step 3 and stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build a custom purpose method that completed the call I needed (to get an OAuth 2 Auth Code).

The Cookies got added automatically, but it did not seem to matter if I added the `CookieContainer` and `UseCookies` settings or not.

Also, `UseDefaultCredentials` did not seem to do anything either.

```
async Task Main()
{   
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddHttpClient("OAuthClient").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new AuthenticationHandler());;
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();  
    var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();   
    
    var authCodeUrl = "https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5001&client_id=client_id_here";
    var authNegotiator = new AuthenticaitonNegotiator(httpClientFactory);
    
    var authCode = await authNegotiator.GetAuthorizationCodeViaKerberosIwa(authCodeUrl);    
    Console.WriteLine(authCode);
}


public class AuthenticaitonNegotiator
{
    private IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;
    
    public AuthenticaitonNegotiator(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory; 
    }
    
    public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationCodeViaKerberosIwa(string authCodeUrl)
    {
        var kerberosToken = GetKerberosTokenViaIwa();
        var authCode = await GetAuthorizationCodeViaKerberos(authCodeUrl, kerberosToken);
        return authCode;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationCodeViaKerberosCredsAsync(string authCodeUrl, string username, string password)
    {
        var kerberosToken = await GetKerberosTokenViaCredsAsync(username, password);
        var authCode = await GetAuthorizationCodeViaKerberos(authCodeUrl, kerberosToken);
        return authCode;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationCodeViaKerberos(string authCodeUrl, string kerberosToken)
    {
        var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("OAuthClient");
        
        var done = false;
        string currentUrl = authCodeUrl;
        string responseText = "";
        bool wasSuccessful = false;
        while (!done)
        {           
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(currentUrl);
            responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // Reset the authenticaiton header if it was set.  (It gets set as needed on each iteration.)
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;          

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                && response.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "WWW-Authenticate" && x.Value.Contains("Negotiate")))
            {
                currentUrl = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;                                        
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Negotiate", kerberosToken);
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
            {
                var redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(redirectUri.Query);
                var code = query.Get("code");
                if (code == null)
                {
                    currentUrl = redirectUri.AbsoluteUri;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If this is the last redirect where we would send to the callback, just grab the auth code.
                    // This saves us from needing to host a service to handle the callback.
                    responseText = code;
                    done = true;
                    wasSuccessful = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                done = true;
                wasSuccessful = false;
            }
        }
        
        if (wasSuccessful == false) 
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Failed to retrive authorization code: \r\n {responseText}");
        }
        
        return responseText;        
    }

    public async Task<String> GetKerberosTokenViaCredsAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        var client = new KerberosClient();
        var kerbCred = new KerberosPasswordCredential(username, password, "YourDomain.net");
        await client.Authenticate(kerbCred);
        var ticket = await client.GetServiceTicket("http/ServerToGetTheKerberosToken.YourDomain.net");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ticket.EncodeGssApi().ToArray());
    }

    public string GetKerberosTokenViaIwa()
    {
        string token = "";
        using (var context = new SspiContext($"http/ServerToGetTheKerberosToken.YourDomain.net", "Negotiate"))
        {
            var tokenBytes = context.RequestToken();

            token = Convert.ToBase64String(tokenBytes);
        }
        return token;
    }
}


public class AuthenticationHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    public AuthenticationHandler()
    {       
        // cURL Equivilant: -L
        AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        MaxAutomaticRedirections = 100;

        // cURL Equivilant: --negotiate -u :
        UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // cURL Equivilant: -b ~/cookiejar.txt
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        UseCookies = true;
    }

}
```

This runs in LinqPad if you add the following NuGet Packages:

- Kerberos.NET
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Http

I also had the following "using" statements:

- System
- System.Collections
- System.Collections.Generic
- System.Data
- System.Diagnostics
- System.IO
- System.Linq
- System.Linq.Expressions
- System.Reflection
- System.Text
- System.Text.RegularExpressions
- System.Threading
- System.Transactions
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq
- System.Xml.XPath
- Kerberos.NET
- Kerberos.NET.Client
- Kerberos.NET.Credentials
- Kerberos.NET.Entities
- Kerberos.NET.Win32
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Http
- System.Net
- System.Net.Http
- System.Net.Http.Headers
- System.Threading.Tasks
- System.Web

Answer (score 2):

## Converting curl flags to `HttpClient`

### `-L`

`HttpClient` should automatically follow redirects because [`HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect` defaults to `true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-5.0).

### `--negotiate -u :`

`HttpClient` will handle negotiation if you supply its constructor with a `HttpClientHandler` that supplies it with credentials. Since you're using default Windows credentials with `-u :`, you can use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request/16018906#16018906):

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
```

### `-b ~/cookiejar.txt`

`HttpClient` can store cookies by supplying its constructor with an `HttpClientHandler` with a [`CookieContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.cookiecontainer?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_CookieContainer):

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() })
```

This depends on the `HttpClientHandler` having [`UseCookies = true`, but it is `true` by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usecookies?view=net-5.0).

### Returning Contents

You can use [`HttpClient.GetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-5.0) and [`HttpResponseMessage.Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpResponseMessage_Content) to read the response of the `HttpClient`

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("");
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

## Everything Combined

Here's what constructing `HttpClient` and making an equivalent request should look like if we explicitly set every value referenced above:

```
var client = new HttpClient(
    new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        // -L
        AllowAutoRedirect = true,

        // --negotiate -u :
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,

        // -b ~/cookiejar.txt
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
        UseCookies = true
    }
);

var response = await client.GetAsync("https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5001&client_id=client_id_here");
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I tested this by mocking the default ASP.NET Core API template with Windows authentication that only allows for `www-authenticate: Negotiate` - if the above isn't working for you, are you able to confirm how your application might differ in its behavior?

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I am awarding the bounty to you, but I am marking my response as the "correct" answer because a few of the settings did not seem to work for me.  But I got it working with a loop to check for a few responses!