# How to I make a cURL command call from .Net Core 3.1 Code

Tags: c#, powershell, curl, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have this complicated cURL command **that is working perfectly**:

```
curl -L --negotiate -u : -b ~/cookiejar.txt  "https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize? scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5001&client_id=client_id_here"
```

However it is not really feasible to replicate in C# using HttpClient.  But
I need to call the cURL command from .Net Core code and get the response back.

**Is there a way to make a normal cURL command call in .Net Core (v3.1)?**

(In case you are interested, this is the details on the cURL command: [Replicate cURL Command Using Redirect and Cookies in .Net Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998324/replicate-curl-command-using-redirect-and-cookies-in-net-core-3-1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via an integrated call to powershell.

1. Install the NuGet Microsoft.Powershell.SDK.
2. Add the `using` statement of `System.Management.Automation`
3. Add the following method:

-

```
public List<string> ExecutePowershell(string command)
{
    var resultsAsString = new List<string>();
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        var results = ps.AddScript(command).Invoke();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            resultsAsString.Add(result.ToString());
        }
    }
    return resultsAsString;
}
```

4. Call it like this:

-

```
void Main()
{
    var results = ExecutePowershell("curl -L --negotiate -u : -b ~/cookiejar.txt  /"https://idp.domain.net/oauth2/authorize? scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5001&client_id=client_id_here/"");
    Console.WriteLine(results);
}
```

I drew this from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777636/16241