# What is PowerShell.Telemetry.ApplicationInsightsTelemetry and can I turn it off?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a C# testing project that uses the `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` NuGet package.  I use it to run a cURL command that I can't seem to get to work with an `HttpClient` (details on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998324/replicate-curl-command-using-redirect-and-cookies-in-net-core-3-1) if you are interested).

It works great, except when I run as a weak user using `RunImpersonated`.  Then I get the following exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Telemetry.ApplicationInsightsTelemetry' threw an exception.

With an inner exception of:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'CreateUniqueUserId' is denied.

I am not sure why my cURL powershell command needs to use Application Insights and I would like to turn it off if possible.

**Is it possible to turn off Application Insights with the Powershell NuGet?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`about_Telemetry` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_telemetry?view=powershell-7.1):

> To opt-out of this telemetry, set the environment variable `POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT` to true, yes, or 1.

So running this when your application starts should do the trick:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT", "1");
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!